# HTML Canvas Not Working (Can't draw stuff)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I'm trying to create a drawing app using HTML and JavaScript

So far, I've been able to print a bunch of stuff on console regarding every method that I was intending to use in the drawing process and it looks like every method is being called as expected. However, nothing is being drawn on the canvas

Here is the code;

```
function CanvasItem({index}){

    let drawing = false

    window.addEventListener('load', handleCanvas)  

    function startedDrawing(e, ctx){
        drawing = true
        console.log("started drawing")
        draw(e, ctx)
    }

    function finishedDrawing(e, ctx){
        drawing = false
        console.log("finishd drawing")
        ctx.beginPath()
    }

    function draw(e, ctx){
        if(!drawing) return 

        console.log('context: ', ctx)
        console.log("x and y", e.clientX, e.clientY)
        ctx.lineWidth ='1'
        ctx.lineCap = 'round'
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red'

        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY)
        ctx.stroke()
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY)
    }

    function handleCanvas(e){
        const canv = document.getElementById(`canvas-item-${index}`)
        let ctx = canv?.getContext('2d')

        if(ctx){
            ctx.width =  window.innerHeight * 9/100
            ctx.height = window.innerHeight * 9/100
            
            window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
                ctx.width =  window.innerHeight * 9/100
                ctx.height = window.innerHeight * 9/100
            })
        }

        canv.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>startedDrawing(e, ctx))
        canv.addEventListener('mouseup', (e)=>finishedDrawing(e, ctx))
    }


    return (
        <canvas id={`canvas-item-${index}`} className="canvas-item">

        </canvas>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where do you create a `CanvasItem` instance?

Comment: There's another component; App.js that is the parent to this and other components. That's where I'm calling this